# What is the correct usage of MVC Areas in MVC4 to create the following solution structure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I would like to set up the following solution structure for my MVC4 application and have the views and controllers route correctly using the Areas model defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Solution

Project.Web
--Areas
----Admin
------Views
--------AdminBlahView1
--------AdminBlahView2
----Supervisor
------Views
--------SupBlahView1
--------SupBlahView2
----Evaluator
------Views
--------EvalBlahView1
--------EvalBlahView2

Project.Controllers
--Areas
----Admin
------AdminBlahView1Controller
------AdminBlahView2Controller
----Supervisor
-------SupBlahView1Controller
-------SupBlahView2Controller
----Evaluator
------EvalBlahView1Controller
------EvalBlahView2Controller
```

Is the "Areas" implementation intended for this purpose and where and how should I place my extension of "ViewLocationFormats" in order for my views and controllers to function properly?

Comment: Just like your views go into a `Views` subfolder in the area folder, your controllers should go in a `Controllers` subfolder in the area folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this? The only difference is that your controllers go in a Controllers subfolder, just like your views go in a Views subfolder.

```
Solution

Project.Web
--Areas
----Admin
------Views
--------AdminBlahView1
--------AdminBlahView2
----Supervisor
------Views
--------SupBlahView1
--------SupBlahView2
----Evaluator
------Views
--------EvalBlahView1
--------EvalBlahView2

Project.Controllers
--Areas
----Admin
------Controllers
--------AdminBlahView1Controller
--------AdminBlahView2Controller
----Supervisor
------Controllers
--------SupBlahView1Controller
--------SupBlahView2Controller
----Evaluator
------Controllers
--------EvalBlahView1Controller
--------EvalBlahView2Controller
```

Comment: Yep. That worked. So my use of Areas for this purpose is correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's incorrect. You don't have to have the controllers and views in separate projects, they can all be in the same project. But if you need to distribute the controllers separately from the views, this is the way to do it with areas.